# How can I do a dirty read in SSMS when I breakpoint my c# application prior to commiting a Transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I have c# code that will run several stored procedures and this is all contained in transaction. As I am going through the methods and procedures, I would like to check data in the backend through SSMS. I have put breakpoints right before a commit occurs and after a Transaction has begun. Is there a way to do a dirty read through SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

Source [Microsoft SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216(v=sql.80).aspx)

Try this

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
select * from TableName;
```

Implements dirty read, or isolation level 0 locking, which means that no shared locks are issued and no exclusive locks are honored. When this option is set, it is possible to read uncommitted or dirty data; values in the data can be changed and rows can appear or disappear in the data set before the end of the transaction. This option has the same effect as setting NOLOCK on all tables in all SELECT statements in a transaction. This is the least restrictive of the four isolation levels.